# updateQueries not getting called

Tags: apollo-client

Why isn't updateQueries getting called for me? I think I'm doing exactly what the docs say and have compared my code to other similar questions. What am I missing?

Package versions:

```
apollo-angular@0.13.0
apollo-client@1.0.4
```

My code:

```
//same es6 module, above my class definition
const RecentSearchesQuery = gql`
  query recentSearch {
    recentSearch {
      id
      query
      lastUpdated
      userId
    }
  }
`;

const RecentSearchesMutation = gql`
  mutation recentSearchSave($query:String!) {
    recentSearchSave(query: $query)
  }
`;

...

//my class method
updateRecentSearches(query: string) {
const updateQueries: MutationQueryReducersMap = {
  RecentSearch: (prev: Object, {mutationResult}) => {
    //execution doesn't get here
    debugger;
    alert('updateQueries handler in RecentSearchesMutation mutation for recentSearch');
    ...
  }
};

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.apollo.mutate<any>({
    mutation: RecentSearchesMutation,
    variables: {query},
    updateQueries
  })
  .subscribe({
    next: ({data}) => {
      resolve();
    },
    error: (error: ApolloError) => {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I never did get `updateQueries` working but the recommended way is now to use `update` (also a mutation option). Using `update` worked for me and this article was a very helpful:

https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/apollo-clients-new-imperative-store-api-6cb69318a1e3